# Getting objects from array with a certain property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have some data:

```
[
 {
   property1: 1,
   property2: 2,     
 },
 {
   property1: 1,
   property2: 3,     
 },
 {
   property1: 2,
   property2: 3,     
 }
]
```

I need to get all objects of this array where `property1=1`. Is there more easier or shorter way to do this than something like:

```
 for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i]["property1"]==1) ....//some action
 }
```

Like in jquery I can use selector for DOM elements, if I need to get all span's with property1=1 I use `$("span[property1=1]").each....`

Comment: I don't have any clue why this is getting downvoted. OP clearly shown his efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter the array with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) based on the property `property1`

```js
var arr = [
   { property1: 1, property2: 2 },
   { property1: 1, property2: 3 },
   { property1: 2, property2: 3 }
];

var res = arr.filter( x => x.property1 === 1);

console.log(res)
```

`Array.filter()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a value that coerces to true.

Array elements which do not pass the callback test are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful than just saying 'filter it' if you would explain.

Comment: @AndrewLi - There's not much to explain, it's one line that filters based on a property?

Comment: Say 'it filter based on the result of calling the callback on each element of the array' and how the return value is a boolean on whether it's kept... there are just too many code-dump posts in the JS tag

Comment: @AndrewLi - If you think I'm not explaining it well enough, post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array as you are doing right now. All you need to do is to create a new array and to push the found objects to that array.

However, there is  array's [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var filteredArray = array.filter(function(obj){
   return obj.property1 === 1;
})
```

Answer (score -4):

kicked out this: Why not use lodash? like:

```
 _.filter(arr, {property1: 1})

use arr.filter(o => { return o.property1 === 1; })
```

Comment: Lodash isn't tagged, so don't include it in an answer. No need for it in an operation like this.

Comment: Hardly merits a whole library for such a simple task

Comment: use an entire library when JS can do this natively? -_-a

Comment: oops, first time to answer question... So, use arr.filter(o => { return o.property1 === 1; })